# How to implement a traffic light functionality in asp.net mvc 2 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

The traffic light will have three light(red, yellow and green), normally they are dark or disabled.

there is 3 states, Error, Warning, Normal and it will be received outside.
if the state is error, then the red light will be blinking.
if the state is error, then the yellow light will be blinking.
if the state is normal, then the green light will be illuminated.

This is the first challenge for me in web developement.
I will be appreciated that someone could help.

Comment: Sounds like possibly homework, although I doubt they'd use MVC for that. In any case, this is a very unusual task for web development.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use javascript to do this. I would make a switch that checks the value of lets say a hidden text box. If the value is normal then do something, if the value is error then do something. I'm writing the code right now.. give me a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks you very much! But how to draw a control just like a traffic light? This is the biggest problem.